# JQuery with Element ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a bit of jquery code to update an element but im having a problem. It wont update and I think its because of the element id?

Here is my JS Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#vote_button_" + $(this).attr('id')).click(function()
        { 
            $("div#vote_count").show().html('<h2>voting, please wait...</h2>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is the HTML Code:

```
<div class="vote_container"> 
    <div class="vote_button" id="vote_button_31"><img src="/images/picture_31.png"></div> 
    <div class="vote_count" id="vote_count">0</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: What are you expecting that `$(this)` will be?

Comment: im expecting it to be the element id so 31? or have i got it totally wrong... I have multiple vote container divs, so i need to have multiple buttons, with multiple ids...

Comment: You got it wrong. `$(this)` in this case refers to the document. The best way to implement a click function for every one of your vote container is to use your classes, like `$("vote_button").click(... use the $(this).attr('id') here ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling it to use the ID of the document (I think).

You can surely just do:

```
    $("#vote_button_31").click(function()
    { 
        $("#vote_count").show().html('<h2>voting, please wait...</h2>');
    });
```

If you want the code to work on all vote buttons try this:

```
    $(".vote_button").click(function()
    { 
        $(this).siblings('.vote_count').show().html('<h2>voting, please wait...</h2>');
    });
```

Comment: But you need to be able to vite for each individual img / div, not for all of them, so i need to use the id, i think.

Comment: The second one will allow you to click each vote button but that click will only show the div inside the same container (That's what .siblings is doing).

Answer (score 2):

`$("#vote_button_" + $(this).attr('id')).click(function()...`

The way you've called it, `this` has no context at all. Since you have a class on the `div` in question, why not use that instead?

`$(".vote_button").click(function() {...`

That will also work if you don't know the id in question when the page is loaded. If you're dynamically adding the `divs` then you might want to use `live` or `delegate`:

`$(".vote_button").live("click", function() {...`

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't select the element directly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("div#vote_button_31").click(function()
        {
            $("div#vote_count").show().html('<h2>voting, please wait...</h2>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I need to have multiple images and dives all with different ids on the same page, so the above wont work.

Answer (score -1):

YOu cannot do this. Instead try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".vote_button").click(function()
    { 
        $("div#vote_count").show().html('<h2>voting, please wait...</h2>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Whosoever down vote my question. Please leave a comment so that I get to know the reason for down vote.

Comment: thanks for your response, but i need to have multiple images with vote buttons on them, so the above wont cover the multiple ids...

Comment: Ok thanks I accept your down vote. But next time, don't forget to write a comment if you do the same for someone else. At least I don't want to be on the receiving end next time.. lol...

Comment: @Tony: Sorry I thought it was you. I just want to know the reason for down vote. Please give me the reason by putting a comment here who down voted.